# Index match unique values with multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have the following list of users on 1 sheet, along with their age and sports interest:

```
A       18        Football
B       19        Rugby
C       18        Football
D       50        Dance
D       21        Rugby
A       25        Football
```

I then have an index match array formula on sheet 2 which is looking up my list of users and outputting them on sheet 1.

Formula:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX('Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$5000, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$36:B36,'Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$5000), 0)),"")
```

This gives me a unique list of users like so:

```
A
B
C
D
```

However, i only want to look up those users who are 18 years old and who are interested in football.

How can i add multiple match criteria to this formula in order to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider a Filter?

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to persevere with a formula, you can force a '1' when the criteria are not fulfilled as follows:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, SIGN(COUNTIF($C$36:C36,'Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10)+('Activity Data'!$C$2:$C$10<>"Football")+('Activity Data'!$B$2:$B$10<>18)), 0)),"")
```

(I am only testing it on 10 rows but should work for any range)

Actually realised SIGN isn't necessary because anything not equal to zero won't be matched so:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$36:C36,'Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10)+('Activity Data'!$C$2:$C$10<>"Football")+('Activity Data'!$B$2:$B$10<>18), 0)),"")
```

[image]

But you may prefer to invert the logic and solve it in the more normal way like this:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF($C$36:C36,'Activity Data'!$A$2:$A$10)=0)*('Activity Data'!$C$2:$C$10="Football")*('Activity Data'!$B$2:$B$10=18), 0)),"")
```

These are array formulae and must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>